# NSIS Calling Plugin functions from uninstaller

Tags: plugins, nsis

In my NSIS installer I have the !include StrFunc.nsh as well as others and call the ${StrCase} function fine when needed.

But I now need to call the ${StrCase} function in my uninstaller but every time I try and call it, it does not compile.

Question is how do I get plugins imported into my uninstaller so I can reference their functions?

I have tried ${un.StrCase} and I have also tried !include un.StrFunc.nsh

But still no luck.

Does someone have a working example they can show me so I can understand and how these are mean to work.

TIA 
Andy

Comment: NSIS version? Compiler error when ${StrCase} is used in uninstaller?

Comment: Thanks Anders

NSIS version 3.03

Compiler error is: Call must be used with function names starting with "un." in the uninstall section.
Usage: Call function_name | [:label_name]
Error in macro FUNCTION_STRING_StrCase_Call on macroline 7
Error in script "D:\NSIS_Projects\NSIS\FL_League\FL_Installer.nsi" on line 1792 -- aborting creation process

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The documentation for StrFunc.nsh](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Docs/StrFunc/StrFunc.txt)  says

> 3.2 How To Use Commands In Uninstall Sections and Functions
>
> ---
>
> Commands with Uninstall Sections and Functions support have "Un" before
>       the words inside curly brackets "{}".
>
> Example:
>
> ---
>
> `${UnStrStr}`
>
> A complete example with both Install and Uninstall Commands:
>       ------------------------------------------------------------
>
> ```
> !include "StrFunc.nsh"
>
> ${StrStr} # Supportable for Install Sections and Functions
>
> ${UnStrStr} # Supportable for Uninstall Sections and Functions
>
> Section
>
> ${StrStr} $0 "OK! Now what?" "wh"
>
> SectionEnd
>
> Section Uninstall
>
> ${UnStrStr} $0 "OK! Now what?" "wh"
>
> SectionEnd
> ```

Comment: Hi Anders, I see where I was going wrong I was putting the dot in which was not needed. 

Thanks once again

Comment: No problem, some of these header files are originally from a 3rd-party and does not follow the normal conventions.